# Token Quota Reached?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I've been using simple-youtube-api package on NPM in my nodejs application for a while and I got this message in console today saying my token was over the quota.

```
{ errors:
   [ { domain: 'youtube.quota',
       reason: 'quotaExceeded',
       message:
        'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.' } ],
  code: 403,
  message:
   'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.' }
```

It's clearly not as seen in this screenshot: [image]

It just reaches 500 requests. And that's in the last 6 hours. So I don't know why I'm getting this forbidden error (403). I believe this is a mistake and should be dealt with.

EDIT: On the graph it says 500, here it says 200:
[image]